# echo $"Puzzling-Bash"_VERSION

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story

[image: Puzzle Image]

You have found a mysterious puzzle (the image above), but you don't know what it is, or what you are required to solve, but the obvious thing you see is a strange string of repeated letters:

```
ABABAAABBAABABA AABBBBABAAABABBAABBBABAAA BABAA AABBA AABBABAABB AABBABBAABABAAA ABABBABAAAABAAB ABAAABABAAABABAAABBAAABBBBABBAABAAA AABBBABABB BABBAABAAABABABABABB ABAAABAABBABAABAABBAABABA ABABBAABBA BABBB BABAAABABB ABABB AABBABAABBABABAAABBBABAAA BABAA ABABA AABBBBABAA AABBBBABBAAABBA ABABBAABBA ABAAABBAABABAAA ABABAAAAAAAABBABABAAABAABAABBBABAAB ABAAABABAA AABBBBBAAA BABAB AABBBABAAB ABAAABABBAAABBB AAAAAAABBB ABABAAABBBABABA BBAAA BABAAABAABAAAAAAABBBBABABABABAABAAAABABB ABAAABBAABAABBBBABABABAAB AABBBBAABBABAAB ABAAB AABBABBAABABAAABABAB AAAAAABAAABABAA ABAAAABABA AABBABBAAAAABBBBAABBABAABAAAABAABBB ABABBAABBAABABB AABBBBABAB AABBB ABAAABAABBABAABAABBB AABBABABABABABAAABBAAABBBBBAAAAABBABABAAABAABAABBAABABA AABBBBABABABABAAABBA BABBAAABBABABAB AABBBABABA AABBABABBAAABBBBABAA BABAAABABBAABBAABABA AABBABABBA AAAABABAAABAABBABABBAABBB AABBABBAAAAABBABABAAABAAB AABBABAABBABAABAABBBABAAB AABBB ABAAABABAA AAAABAABBABABABABABAAABBA ABAAABABABABAAB AABBBBABBBAABBA ABABAAABBB AABBBBAABBABAABAABBAABAAABABBAABAAABABABABABAAABBBABAAB AABBABBAABAABBABABAA AAABAAABBB ABABAAABBAABABA AABBBBABBAABAAABABAAABAAB AABBABABAAABAAB ABAAB BABBBAABBB AABBBBAABBABAABAABBB BABAAABABAAABBB BABBBAABBBBABAA ABAAAABABA ABAAA ABABAABAAAAABBBBBAABABAAABAABB ABAAA AABBB AAAABAABBBBABAAABABBAABBAABAAB ABAAABAABBABABA AABBABBAAB BABABABABAAABBAABAAB BABABABABBAAAAA BABAAABABAABAAAABAAB AABBBBBAABAABBB ABABAAAAAB BAABB ABAAB ABAAA AABBABABAAABABAAAAABAABBBBABAA AABBB AABBABBAAAABAAABABABABAABAAAABAABBABAABB ABABA BABBAAABBBBABABABAAB ABAAABABAAABABAAABBBABABA BAABB ABAAAAABBABBAAA BAABB ABABA AABBB ABABAAABBA BABBBABAAABABABABABA ABABB BABAAABABAABAAAAABBBBBAAAAABBB ABAAB BAABBABABA ABAAABABBBAABBABABAAABAABAABBAABABB AABBA AABBA ABAABAAAABABAAABABAAABABB AABBA ABAAABABABABABB AABBABAABB ABABB AABBBBABBBAABBBBABABABAAB AABBBBAABBABABBABAAAABABA AABBABABAAABABBAABBBABAAABBAABABAAABABABABAABAABBA ABAAA AABBBBAABB AAAAA BAABBABABAABAAAABABA ABAAA ABAABABAAA BABBAAABBA ABABB AABBB ABAAABABAB AAAAAAABBABABAAABABBAABBA ABAAABBAAA ABABAAAAABAABBB ABAABAABBBABABA ABAAAABAAABBAAAAABBA AABBBABABB AABBABABAB BBAAAAABBBBABABABAABABAAA AABBA AABBA BBAABAABBA ABAAA ABAAABABAB AABBA ABAABAABBAABABA AABBA BABABABAABAAABAABAAABAABBABAABAABBAABAAB AABBB AABBBAABBBBBAAA BAABBABAABABAAAABAAB AABBABABABABAABAABBBAABBABBAABAABBBBAABB BABBB BABAAABAABAAAAAAABBB ABABBABAAA AABBBBABAAABABAABAAA BBAAB BABABABABB BABBAAABBA ABABBAAAAA ABAABAABBA BABABABABB AABBABABBBAABBBBAABBABABAAABBAABAAB AABBBBABAB AABBABABBB ABABBABAAAABABB AABBABABBBAABBB ABAAABAABBABABAAABBBABAAB AABBBBABBAABAAABAABB AAAAAABAAA AABBAABAAB BBAAB BABAB AAAABAABBBBABABABABAABAAA BABBA BABAB ABAAABABAB ABAAA AABBB ABAAABAABBABABBAAAAAABAAABABAB ABAAAABAAB ABAAABABBBAABBABABABABABBAAAAB BAABBABABAAABBAABABA ABAAA AABBBBAABB AAAAAABAAABAABBABAABAABBBABABB AABBBBABABABAAB ABAAA AABBABAABBABABAABAAAABABA ABAAABAABBABABBABAAAAABBABABBAABAAABABAA AABBBABABA AABBABAABBABAABABAAAAABBBBBAABABAAA AABBA AABBABABBBAABBABABABABABB BAABBABAABAABBAABABB BBAAAABAAABABAAABABB ABAAABABABABABAAABBBABAAB BABAAABAABAABBAABAAABABBBABAAABAABBABABAABAAAABAAB BABBBAABBABAABBABAABAAAAAABAAABABAAABAABAABBAABABA BBAABABAAABAABBABABBAAABA BABAAABAABAABBB BAABB ABAAABBAAA BABAAABABBAABBBABAAB ABAAABABABABABBAABBBAABBABBAAA BABABABAABABAAAABABA AABBABABBBABAAABABABABAABAAAAAAABBABABABABAABAABBBABABA BAABB AABBBAABBBBBAABAABBABAABBABABBABAAAABABB AABBA AABBABAABBABABB AABBBBABABABABAABAAAABABB AABBBBABBBABAAABAABBABABAAAAABAABBA AABBB AABBBBBAAAAABBBBABAA AAABAABAAABABABABABAAABBAABAAB AABBB ABABB AABBBBBAABAABBBBABAAABAABAABBA AABBB ABAABAABBAABAAABABBBAABBBBABABABAAB ABABB AABBBBABAAABABBABAAAABAAABABBAAABBA ABAAB ABABA AABBBBABBBAABBA ABAABAAAABAABBB ABABAABAAAABABB AABBA AABBABABAAABABBAAAAAAABBABABAAABAABABAAAABAAB ABAAABABBAABAAABABABABABAAAAAAAABBABABAAABABAABAAAABAAB BABABABAABAABBAAABBABBAAA BABAB AABBB BABAAABABBAABBAABAAABABBBABAAA ABABAAABBBABABA ABAAABABAAABAABAAAAAAABBBBABABABABAABAAAABABB BBAABAABBABABABABAABAAAAAAABBABAABB AABBAABAAB AABBBBBAAAAABBBBAABBABAABAAAAAAABBBBABABABABAAABBA AABBABABBBABAAABABAB AAAAAABAAABAABB AABBAABABB BBAAAAABBABAABBABABBAAABA BABAAABABAABAAAABABB ABAABAABBAABAAABABBB ABABAABAAAABABA BAABBABAAB ABAAABABBAABAAABAABBABABBAABBA AABBBBBAAB ABABBAAABAAABBB ABABBABAAAABABB AABBBBABBA BABAAABABAAAABA BABAB ABAAAABABA ABAAABABBAAABBBBABAA AAAABAABBA ABABAAABBB AABBBBAABBABABBAABBA BAABBABABBAABBB AABBA AABBBBABAAABAAB BAABBABABB ABABA ABAAABABAAABABAAABBBAABBBBABBAAABBBBABABABAABAABBB ABAAABBAABABAAABABAAABABAAABBA AABBBBABAA AABBA BBAAAABAAABABABABAABAABBA AABBB AABBABABABABABBAAABAAABBA ABAAABABBAAABBBBAABBABABBAAAAA ABABAAABBAABABB ABAAABBAAAABAAABABAA AAABAAABBBBABAA AABBAABABB AABBA ABABAABAAAABAAABABBA BAABB AABBAABABA AABBABBAABAABBABAABBABABAAAAAA BABAAABABAABAAAABABB ABAAABBAAAAABBB ABAAABABAA AABBBABAAB ABAAABBAAAABAAABABAAABAABAAAABABAAA ABABA ABABA AABBBBAABB BABBAAABBBBAABBABABB ABABA AABBABABAAABAABAABBBABAAABABBAABAAA ABAABAABBBABABB AABBA ABAAABABAB AAABAAABBBBABAAABAABAABBA AABBABBAABAABBB ABAABAAAABABAAABABAAABABB ABAAB AABBBBABBBAABBBBABAA AABBBBABABABAABAABBBABABB ABAAABABBBABAAA ABABAAAAAA ABAABABAAA BAABBABABA BABBB ABABAAABBB ABAAABABABABAABAABBAAABBABABBB BABAAABABBAABBBABAAB BABBAAABBABABABABAAB AABBABABAAABAAB ABABB AABBBBBAAAAABBABAABBABAABAAAAAABAAABABAB ABAAB AABBABABABABAAB ABAAA AABBB ABAABAABBAABABB ABAAABABAB AABBAAABBBBABBAAABBBBABABABABA ABABB ABAAABBAAAABAAABAABBABABA ABAAABABAA AABBBABAAB BBAABAABBBBAABB AAABAAABBBBABAAABABBABAAAABABA AABBABAABB AABBAABAAABBAAAAABBBBABAA ABABA BABBBAABBABABAAABABAAAAAAAABBABABABABAAB AABBA ABAAABABAAABABA AABBABABAAABABB AABBABBAAAAABBABAABBABABBAAABAAABBBBABAAABAABAABBBABABA AABBABAABBABAABAABBBABAAABBAABABAAA ABAAB ABABB AABBBBABAAABAABABAAAABAAABBAAB BABAAABABAABAAAABABA BABBAABAAA ABABB AABBABABAA ABAAAABAAB ABAAAAABBA AABBBBABAA AABBBABABB ABABA ABAAA ABAAABABAA AABBAABABB AABBABABBBAABBABABAAABABAAAABA BABAA AABBAABABB BBAAAAABBBBABABABABAAABBAABABB BABABABABAABAAAAABBBBBAABAABBB AABBAABAAB ABAAABBAABABAAABABABABABBAAABAAABBBBABABABABAAABBAABABB BAABBABABAABAAAAABBBBBAAAAABBABABAAABABBAABBAABABB AABBA BABABABAABAAAAAABAAABABAAABABAABAAAABAAB BAABBABABB BABBAAABBABABAAABABAAABBB ABAAA AABBA ABAABAAABAAABBABABAAABABBABAAAABAAB ABAAABABBA ABABBAAABAAABBBBABABABABBAABBAABABB AABBABABABABAAB AABBABABBBAABBABABABABAAB ABABA ABAAABABBBAABBABAABB AAAAB ABABAAABBBABABB AABBBBABAAABABAAABBAAABBABBAAAAABBABABAAABABBAABBBABAAB ABAAABBAABABAAABABABABABBAAAABAABBB ABABBAABBAABAAB AABBBBABAB AABBBABAAABABBA BAABB AABBBABAAB AABBABBAAB BABAB AAAAB ABABAABAAAABAAB ABAAABABBB BABABABABAAAAAB BABAAABABBAABBA BBAAAAABBB ABABA ABAAABABABABABBAABBB BABBAABAAABAABBABABAAAABAAABBBBABABABABAAABBBABAAB BBAABAABBA ABABA ABAAABABABABABAABAAAABAAB BAABBABABAAABBB BBAAA BABAAABABAAABBAABABA AABBA ABABBAABBBABAAABABBAABAAABABAA ABAAABABAB AABBA BBAABAABBBBABABABAABAABBA ABAAA AABBA AABBBBAABBABABA ABABA AABBABABABABAAB BBAAAAABBA ABABAABAAAABABA AABBBBAABBABABBAABBBAABBBBABBBAABBABAABB ABABB ABAABAABBAAABBBBBAAA AABBAABABB ABAAABABAA ABAAA BABBBAABBBBABABABABBAABBAABAAB ABAAABABBBAABBB ABAABAAAABAABBBBABAAABABAABAAAABAAB AABBA ABAABAABBA BBAABAABBABABAAABABBAABBAABABB AABBB BABAA AAABAABAAABABABABABAAABBBABABA AABBBBAABBABABBAABBB BABBBAABBABABABABABB ABABA ABAAA AABBA AABBB ABAABABAAAABAAB BAABBABABAAABBBABAAABBAAAABAAABABABABAABAABBB AABBABABBBAABBABABABABABAAAAABABAAABABAAABABAAABBB BABAA AABBAABAAABABBBAABBA AABBABABAA AABBABAABB ABAAAABABB BAABBABAAB ABAAABABBAABAAABABABABABB BAABBABABB AABBA BABAA ABAAA ABAAABABAAABAABAABBA BBAAA BAABB AABBBABABA ABAAABABBBABAAABAABB AAABAABAAA ABAABABAAAABABA AABBABABBBAABBABAABBABAABAAABAAABBABAABBABABAAABBB AABBABBAAA BABAAABABB AABBABABAAABABAAABBBABAAB ABAAABABBA BABABABABAAAAAAAABBABABAA AABBBABABB AABBB ABAABAABBBAABBBBABBB ABABBAABBBABAAB BAABBABABBABAAAAABBABBAAAAABBABABAA ABABB BABABABAABAAABAAABBABAABB AABBA ABAAABABAAABABBAAABAAABBB ABAABAABBAABAAB AABBBBABBBAABBBBAABBABABBAAABA BABABABAAB ABAAB ABAAABAABB AABBBAABBBBBAABAABBB ABABBAABBA AABBBBBAABABAAABABABABABA AABBA ABAAAABABB ABAAABAABBABABBAABBBAABBBBABBAAABBABAABB AABBBABABA AABBA ABAABAABBAAABBABABBB ABABAAABBB ABABAAABBB BABBBAABBBBABAAABAABABAAAABABB AABBABABAA AABBA BABABABAABABAAA AABBA AABBBBABABABABAAAABAAABBBBABABABABAAABBAABABB AABBABBAABABAAABABAA AAABAABAAABAABBABABB ABABA AABBBBABABABABBAABBAAABBBBABBBABAAABABABABABAABAAA AABBBBBAAAABAAABAABBABAABAAAAAABAAABAABBABABAAABBBABABA ABAAABBAABAABBABABABABAAB AABBB ABABB ABABB AABBABABBBAABBB ABAABAAAABABAAA ABABB AABBABABBB BABABABABBAAAAB BABAAABABAAABBB AABBABABBAABAAABABAAABABAAAAAAAABBBBABAAABAAB ABAAB BABAB AABBAABAAABABBB BABAAABAAB ABABA AABBABAABB AABBA BABBBABAAABAABB AABBBABABB AABBBBABBBAABBABAABBABAAB BAABB AABBA AABBABABBBAABBA ABAABAAAAAABAAABABABABAABABAAAABABB BBAAB BAABBABAAB AABBA ABABA AABBBBAABBABABAAABBAAABBABABBAAABBBBAABBABABAAABBB AABBBBABAAABAABABAAAABAAABBAAAAABBA ABABBABAAAABABB AABBBBABAB AABBABBAAAAABBBBABABABABB ABABB AABBABAABBABABBAABBAABAAABBAABAABBBBAABB ABABA AABBBBABBAAABBABAABBABABAAAAAAABAAA AABBAABAAB AABBABBAAAAABBB ABAABAAABAAABBBBABAAABABB ABAAB AABBBBBAABABAAABABAB AAABAAABBA ABABAAABBAABABB AABBABABABABAABAABBAABAAA AABBB ABAABAABBA ABAAABAABBABABAAABBAABAAA ABABB ABABB AABBBBABBA BABAB AAABAAABBA ABABBAABBA AABBB AABBB ABABBAAAAA BAABB AABBAABAAB AABBBAABBBBBAAAABAAABAABBABAAB ABAAB ABAAABBAAA BABABABABB ABAAABABAAABABAAABBAABAAB ABAAA AABBBBAABBABAAB AABBBBAABBABABAABAAAABAAB BABABABABBABAAAABAAABBAAA BAABBABABAAABBBABABA ABAAABAABBABABBAABBAAABBABBAAA BABAAABAABAABBAABAAB AABBBBABAAABABBAABBB BAABBABAABAABBAABAAB ABAAABABAB AABBAAABBB AABBABABAA AABBAABABA ABAAABABBAAABBB AAAAAABAAA ABAABABAAAABAAB ABAAABABBB BABAB AABBBBABAAABABBABAAAABABB AABBBBBAAAABAAABABAAABABAAAAAB BABAAABAABAABBB ABAAA BABABABAABAAAAAABAAABABAAABABB ABABA ABAAA ABAAA ABABB AABBABAABBABAABABAAAABABA AABBABBAAA AAABAAABBABABAA AABBBABABB AABBBBBAAAAABBA ABABAAAAAAABAAABABAAABABAAABBAABABA ABAAABBAAB BABABABABBAAABA BABAAABABBABAAAABABA AABBABABABABAABAABBAAABBABABBBAABBABAABB ABABB BABBBABAAA ABABAAAABAAABBABABAB AABBBBAABBABABB BABBBAABBABABAA BABAAABABBABAAAAABBABBAAAABAAABAABBABAABAABBBABAAB AABBB AABBBBAABB AABBBBAABBABABAAABBA AABBABAABBABABA BABBB ABAABABAAAABABA ABAAABBAABAABBBBABAAABABAAAAAAAABBABAABBABABBAABBBABABA BABAAABABAABAAAABAAABBAAAAABBABAABBABAABAABBBABABB ABAAAABAAA BABAAABABA AABBABABBBAABBABAABBABABBAAAABABAAABAABBABABAAABBB AABBBBABAAABAABAABBAABAAA AABBABABAA AABBA ABAAABBAAAAABBA ABABA AABBBBAABBABABBAABBAABABB ABAAABABBAABAAABAABBABAABAAAABAABBBBABAB ABAAAABABA AABBBBAABBABAAB AABBBBBAAAABAAA ABAABAABBBABAAB AABBBBBAABAABBBBAABBABABBAAAABAABBABABABABAABAABBBABAAB BABAAABABAAABBB BABBAABAAABABAA AABBAABABA AABBBBABBAAABBA ABABAAAAABABAAA ABAAAABAAB ABAAABAABB ABAAA BABBBABAAABABAB AABBABABBAAABBBBABABABABB AABBABAABBABAABAABBB ABABAAABBAAABBABBAAAAABBB ABABAAABBA AABBABAABBABABB BABBB AABBAABABB BABBAABAAABABABABABAAAAAAAABBBBABAA AABBA AABBBBABAA AAAAAAABBABABAB AABBBABAAB BABAAABAABAABBBABAAABBAABABAAABABAAABABAAABBBABABB BABAAABABBAABBBAABBA ABAAABAABB ABAAAABABB BAABBABAABAABBAAABBBBABBB BAABBABAAB ABABB AABBA ABAAABABAB AAAABAABBBBAABBABAAB ABABA AABBB AABBBBAABBABAABAAAAB BABAB AABBA ABAAABABBAAABBABAABBABABA BAABBABABBAABBA ABAAABAABBABAAB ABAAABABBAABAAABABABABABBAABBBABAAB ABAAABABAAABABAABAAAABAAABABBA BABAAABABB ABAAB AABBBBABBBAABBBBABAA BABAA AABBBABAAB AABBABBAAA BABABABABBAAABAAABBBBABAAABABAAABBAABABA ABAAABBAAAABAAABABABABABBAAAABABAAABAABB AABBB ABAAABBAAB BAABB AABBABABABABAABAABBA AABBBBABABABABBAABBBAABBABABBAAABBA AABBBABAAB AABBABABAAABABBAABBB BBAABAABBBBAABB AABBBABAAB BBAAA BAABB AAAABAABBABAABBABABBAABBA BBAAB BAABBABAABAAABAABAAA ABABBABAAAABABA ABAAABABABABABBAABBAAABBABBAAAAABBABAABBABABA BABAAABABAABAAAAABBB AABBABABAAABAABAABBBABABB AABBBBABBA BAABBABABAAAABA BAABBABAABAABBAABAAB ABAAABBAAA BABAAABABBAAAAAAABBABABAA ABAAAABABB AABBA ABABAAABBBAABBBBBAAB BABABABABAABAAAABABB BBAABAABBABABABABAABAAAABAABBABABAAABAABAABBB AABBB ABAAABABAAABABB BABABABABBABAAAABABB AABBBBABBBAABBBBABABABAAB AABBBBABABABABAAABBAABABB ABAAABAABBABABAABAAA BABBBAABBABABAAABABBABAAAABABA AABBBBBAAAAABBBBAABBABABBAAABAAABBABABABABAABAABBA AABBBBABABABAAB ABAAABABAAABABB ABABB AABBBBAABBABABBAABBAAABBBBBAABABAAABABAAABABAABAAAABAAB ABAAABABABABAABAABBA BBAABAABBABAABBABABBAABBBABABA AABBA AABBBBAABBABABA AABBABABABABAABAABBBABABA AABBBBABBB BABABABAABAAAAAABAAABABABABABBAABBB AABBBBBAAAAABBBBAABB AAAAAABAAABABAAABABA ABAAB ABAAABAABBABABBABAAA BAABBABABA AABBBBABAB ABAAAABAAABABBBAABBABAABBABABB ABABB AABBABABBBAABBBBABAAABAABAAAABABAAABAABBABABBAABBBABABA AABBA AABBAAABBABABBAAABBBBABAAABABAABAAAABABB AABBB ABAAA ABAABAAAABABAAA AABBB BAABB AABBAABAAABABBB BAABBABABB AABBBBABAA AABBBAABBABBAABAABBBBABABABABAAABBAABABB BAABBABABB AABBBBABBAAABBBBABAAABAABABAAAABABB AABBABABABABABA AABBABBAAAABAAA ABABBAABBAABABA AABBBBABBB ABABAAAAAA BABABABAABAABBAABABA BBAAA ABABBAAAAAABAAABABAA AABBBABABA AABBBBABAAABAAB ABAAABBAABAABBBBABAA ABAAAABABB AABBBBAABBABAAB AABBB AABBABABABABABAAABBAABABA AABBABABABABABA ABAAA BABAAABABAABAAAABAAB AABBBBABAAABAABAABBBAABBBBBAAAAABBABAABBABABBAABBB AABBB AAAAAABAAABAABBABABB ABABA AABBABBAABAABBBBAABB AAABAABAAABABAAABAABABAAAABAAB BBAABAABBABABAB AAAABAABBBBABAAABAABABAAAABAAB AABBABABBA BABABABABAAAAABAABBB ABABAABAAAABABA AABBBBABBA ABABBAAAAB BABABABABBABAAAABABB AABBABABBAAABBBBABAAABAABAAABAAABBA ABABA ABABA AABBABABBBAABBB AAABA BABABABABBABAAAABABA ABAAABABABABABBAABBBAABBBBBAABAABBA ABABA ABABB AABBABBAAB ABAAABABAAABABBAABBAABAAB ABABBABAAAAABBBBABBBAABBBBABAAABAABAABBBABABA ABAAABABAA AABBBAABBABBAAAAABBBBABAAABABBABAAAABABB BABBA ABABBAAAABAABBBBABAB AABBAABAAB ABABBABAAA BABBBAABBBBABABABABBAABBB ABAAABBAABAABBB ABAAB AABBB ABABA ABAAABABAAABABAAABBBABAAABABBBAABBA ABABAAABBAABABA BBAABAABBA ABAAABAABB ABAAB ABABAAABBAABAAABBAAA ABABAAABBBABAAB AABBBBABAAABAABAABBBABAAA BAABBABAAB ABAAB BABBBABAAA ABAABAAAABAABBBBABAAABABBAABBAABABA AABBBBBAAAAABBBBABAAABABBAAAAAAABBABABAA ABAAAABAAB AABBA ABAAABAABBABABBAAAABAABBABABABABABBAABBA AABBBBBAAA BABAAABABBAAAABAABBBBABABABABB ABAAB AABBAAABBABBAAAABAAA ABABBABAAAABABB AABBB ABAAAAABBBBABBBAABBABAABBABAABABAAAABABB AABBBBABAA AAAABABAAABAABB ABAAAABAAB ABAAA AABBABAABB AABBA ABAAAABAAB ABAAA ABABAAABBBAABBBBBAAB BABAAABABBAABBBABABB AABBBBABAB ABAAABABBBAABBB ABABBAABBBABABB AABBBBBAAA BABAA AABABAABBB ABABAABAAA ABAAABABBBAABBB ABABBAAAABAABBABAABBABAAB ABABA AABBABABBBAABBA ABAAABABAA ABAAABABBAAABBABAABBABABAAAABA BABABABABA ABABB BABABABABBAABBBAABBABABBA ABABBAABBB ABAAA BABABABABAAAAAAAABBBBABAAABABAAABBBABABA ABABA AABBABBAABAABBBBABABABABAABAAA AABBBBABBAAABBBBABABABABA BABAB ABAAAABAAB BAABBABABB ABAAABABBAAABBB ABABA ABABB AABBBBABBBABAAA AABBBBABABABAABAABBAABABA AABBBBABAAABABB AABBABABBAAABBABAABBABABBABAAAABAAB AABBABABABABABA BBAABAABBABABAB AABBB AABBA AABBBBABABABAABAAAAAAABBBBABAAABABBAABBAABABB ABAAA BAABBABAABAAAAA BABABABABAAABBBABAAB AABBABABBA BAABBABABBAAAAAAABBABABABABABBAABBBABAAB ABAAABABAB ABAAABBAABAABBABAABBABABBABAAA ABAAABABABABAABAABBAABAAA BAABB ABAAA AABBBBABAAABABAAABBBAABBABABBAAABBBBAABBABABBAABBBABABB ABAAA BABABABAABAAAAA BAABBABABBAABBAABAAB BABBA BAABB AAABAAABBABABABABABAAABBAABABA AABBA AABBB BABABABAAB ABAAABBAABAABBB ABAABAAAAAABAAABAABBABABAABAAAABAAB ABAABAABBBABAAABABBBAABBBBABABABAABAABBA ABAAABABABABABBAABBA BABBBAABBBBAABB AABBAABABA ABAAABBAABABAAA ABAAB AABBABAABBABABAAABBAABABA ABAAABAABBABAABABAAA AABBBBABAAABABA AABBBBABBAAABBABABAA ABAAABABABABAABABAAAABABB ABAAABABBA BABABABABA AABBABAABB AABBAABABA ABAAABABBBABAAA ABAABAAAABAABBB AABBBABABA ABAAABBAAAAABBABABABABAABAAAAAABAAABABABABAABAABBAABAAB ABAAABABAAABAABAAAABAABBABAABBABAAB ABABA AABBA AABBABABABABAABAAABAAABBBBABAAABABAAABBA ABABAABAAA BABBBAABBABABAAABAAB ABAAB ABAAABBAAB BABAAABABB ABAAA ABAABABAAAABABA AABBABABAAABABAAABBAAABBABBAAAAABBABABAAABABBAABBA BABABABABBAABBAABAAABBAABAABBABABAAABABB ABABA BAABBABAABAAAAAAABBBBAABBABAABAABBBABABA AABBBBABBAAABBBBABABABABBAAAAA ABAABABAAAABABA ABAAA ABABAAABBBAABBA ABAABABAAAABABB ABAAABBAAB ABAABAAAAAAABBABABAAABABBABAAAABABA BABBBAABBBBAABBABABBAAABA ABAAA AABBABAABBABABAAABBAABAAABABBBAABBABABABABABAAABBA ABAAB ABAAA AABBABABABABABBAABBAABABA AABBABABAA AABBB AABBABABABABAABAABBA BAABBABABBAABBBABAAABBAABAABBABABABABABAAABBAABAAB AABBBBABBAAABBABABAAABABBAAAAAABAAABABABABABBAABBBABAAB BABBB BABAAABABA BABAB ABABB ABAAABBAAA BAABBABABAAAAAAAABBBBABABABAABAABBBABABB ABAAABBAAAAABBABAABBABABAAAAAAAABBBBAABB ABABA ABAAABAABB AABBB BBAABABAAABABABABAABAABBAABABB ABAAABABAAABABAAABBAAABBB AABBA ABABB ABAAB BABBAAABBABAABBABABBAAAABAABBA ABAABAABBA AABBABABBB BABABABABBAAAABABAAABABAAABABBAABBA AABBABABAAABABB BABBAAABBABAABB AABBAABABB BAABBABAABAABBB BBAABAABBBBAABBABABAABAAAABABB AABBB AABBABABAAABABBAABBA AABBBBBAAB BABAAABAABAAAAAAABBB ABABBAABBAABAAB BABAB AABBABABBAAABBBBABAAABABBAABBBABABA AABBABAABBABABAAABBAABAAABBAAAABAAA ABAAB ABABA AABBBBABBA BABAB AAAABABAAABABAAABABAAABBBABAAB AABBABABBBAABBABAABBABABB AABBB ABAAB ABABB BBAAAAABBABABABABABBAAAABAABBBBAABBABABAABAAAABAAB AABBBBBAAAABAAABABAAABAABAAABAAABBABABABABABBAABBBABABB ABAAABABBAAABBABABAA AAAAAAABBABABAA ABABB AABBBBAABBABABAAABBAAABBB AABBBBABABABAABAABBB ABAAA AABBB AAAAA ABABBAABBBABABA ABAAABABAA ABAAA BBAAA ABAAB AABBABABABABABBABAAAABAAABABBAABAAABAABBABAAB ABAAB AABBB AABBA AAAABAABBBBABABABAABAABBBABAAB BABAAABAABAABBB AABBABABABABABBAABBBABABB BBAAAABAAABABABABABBAAAAB BABAB ABAAB ABAAABABAA AABBBAABBBBBAABABAAA ABAABAABBBABAAB AABBBBABBBABAAABABAAABABAAAAAAAABBBBABAAABAABAABBAABABB AABBABABAAABABAAABBAAABBABBAAA BABABABABAABAAA BAABBABABBABAAAAABBABABBBAABBABAABBABABAAABBB AABBA AABBABABABABABBAAAABAABBBBABABABABAABAAAABAAB AABBABABBBAABBABABAAABAABAAABAAABBABAABB AABBA BBAAA ABABAAAABAABAAABABABABABBAABBAABABA AABBABABBBABAAABABAAABABAAAAABAABBB ABAABAABBB BABABABABBAABBAAABBBBBAAAAABBABABABABABBAABBBABABB AABBABABABABABAAABBAAABBA ABAAABABAAABABAAABBAABABA AABBABABBAAABBB ABABAAAAAA BAABBABAABAABBAABABA AABBBBBAAAAABBABABABABABBAAABAAABBBBABAAABABAABAAA AABBABABABABABB AABBBBBAAAAABBBBAABBABABBAABBB AABBBBABAAABABBAABBAAABBABABBAABAAABABAA ABAAAABAAB AABBABABABABABAAABAA
```

"*Is this a relevant string, or is the actual puzzle hidden somewhere else? I guess I have to find out!*", you tell yourself.

Can you uncover the mystery, and solve this strange puzzle?

Edit: Hint:

> Find the correct page.

Edit: Larger hint:

> The path you must seek is not within the text. 
>  Ignore the text. 
>  Also, remember, [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)

Edit: Another larger hint:

> Steganography that is present on one page only.

Edit: Another hint:

> Ignore the first page.

Comment: I am *not* transcribing that.

Comment: Well, if you use indentation for the "code appearance" it will look much better than with back ticks.

Comment: As a matter of puzzle-solving, what kind of puzzler looks at the hint before the puzzle?!

Comment: First it says `exe show hint`, then only it says `exe show image` and `exe show text`.

Comment: This puzzle smells, suspiciously, like Bacon.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I thought so too, but it all decrypts in to a funny spot.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Bacon cipher? Yes, that cipher is used somewhere in the process, you're right. But be careful of the red herrings.

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't have a tool to decipher multi-word bacon ciphers, nor the time to do it by hand, so my comment was simply intended as a hint for others.

Comment: I have a feeling that this should be tagged [tag:steganography]...

Comment: well after bacon cipher, text converts to jibrish and really dont have a frequency rate anywhere near english. So, I assume with the text we should do something like jumping letters and lines but i really cant see a pattern there. Also by right page, I think he means right most page to start with?!

Comment: @CipherRiddle Fair enough. I still think this has to do with a certain type of steganography ;)

Comment: I've rolled back the title to make it less clickbaity. All-caps online is considered equivalent to yelling, which is impolite.

Comment: @Deusovi Seriously? Oh now you have a rivalry against me or something? Relax man, being an SE mod is not easy I know but you have to maintain equal standards for people, and no, I was never trying to be impolite, why would I? On 4chan what you're saying would be a meme to them, but this is SE and we don't do that kind of stuff usually.

Comment: @humn I'm not sure how to design further hints. I think really if you download or use certain software (see the hints for more information) and try to find the answer to the puzzle, you might be able to. So I'm not really sure if I should have more hints, but I don't really know.

Comment: Do line or word lengths carry any information at all?  If so, a list of word and line lengths might be good. I did a paint fill of the image and didn't see anything, although that stripe between pages 4 and 5 sure does look suggestive.

Comment: @humn The text on the images is not relevant at all It is more of a a decoy.

Answer (score 1):

Partial to kickstart someone maybe:

> Between the fourth and fifth pages in the image there is a vertical line which might indicate a page break.

Comment: Might. Or might not. :D

Answer (score 1):

**The below partial answer is invalid.**

Per hint #2, the answer is not based on the text, nor any property of the text such as those listed below. I will update this answer if/when I find inspiration.

---

Some observations which may or may not prove useful:

- The line-wrap threshold is set to 72 characters. That is, if a word would make the line longer than 72 characters, it goes to the next line.
- Various other counts are as follows:

  ```
  Page                    1     2     3     4     5     6
  Lines                  54    54    54    54    54    24
  Words                 204   190   200   179   187    68
  Letters (no spaces)  3210  3230  3050  3135  3145  1325
  Letters (w/ spaces)  3413  3419  3249  3313  3331  1392
  Groups of 5 letters   642   646   610   627   629   265
  Number of A's        1780  1806  1669  1708  1725   729
  Number of B's        1430  1424  1381  1427  1420   596
  ```

Comment: Ah, right. My brain kinda skipped over that, apparently.